# two set interval function in single PHP file is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function updateChatAJAx1()
{
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
         //The response
        document.getElementById('content1').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "open_ajax.php?mode=ref", true);

    ajaxRequest.send(null);

}


$(function(){

    setInterval(function () {

        updateChatAJAx1(); // It is javascript function which request to ajax file.

    }, 2000);
});

$(function(){

    setInterval(function () {

        updateChatAJAx(); // It is javascript function which request to ajax file.

    }, 2000);
});
```

when page is loaded both functions updateChatAJAx() and updateChatAJAx1() are working together. I want to call only one function at a time of some time interval.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call one function after the other has executed?

Comment: I want these two functions to be called on some condition. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand. What condition? Can you give an example?

Comment: I am basically developing a chat application, in which there are two modes: group chat and personal chat. After sending the message i want to auto refresh the content, and therefore i have created these two functions for two modes. when I use personal chat then only one set interval function should be called with updateChatAJAx() and when I use group chat then only set interval with updateChatAJAx1() should be called. But however when i run the code, both the functions run together at the same time. Any suggestion how can i overcome this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading execute both operations together.

```
updateChatAJAx(); 
updateChatAJAx1();
```

Then setInterval for both actions

```
   var flag=0;
    $(function(){

        setInterval(function () {

          if(flag==0)
           {
             updateChatAJAx(); 

           }
          else
           {
             updateChatAJAx1();

           }

        }, 2000);
    });
```

Change the flag to choose operation.

```
flag=0 -> updateChatAJAx();
```

and

```
flag=1 -> updateChatAJAx1();
```

Answer (score 0):

change time in one of your function like change 2000 to 3000 or what you want.

Comment: I want these two functions to be called on some condition. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    setInterval(function () {
        updateChatAJAx();
        updateChatAJAx1(); // It is javascript function which request to ajax file.

    }, 2000);
});
```

please try like this

Comment: I am basically developing a chat application, in which there are two modes: group chat and personal chat. After sending the message i want to auto refresh the content, and therefore i have created these two functions for two modes. But however when i run the code, both the functions run together at the same time. Any suggestion how can i overcome this problem??

Comment: how you want to run these two function

Answer (score 0):

If you want one function to run when you use one mode and another function to run when you use a different mode, you will need some way of determining which mode you are running in.

For example:

```
<button id="group">Group chat</button>
<button id="personal">Personal chat</button>

$("#group").on("click", function(){
  setInterval(updateChatAJAx, 2000); 
});

$("#personal").on("click", function(){
  setInterval(updateChatAJAx1, 2000); 
});
```